# Google App Engine tutorial questions

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am interested in importing Google contacts into my web-application.
I have gone through some of the Google App Engine tutorials on youtube and I have the following questions.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIIgcIqoPw
(the above tutorial, my question are applicable to any google api)

1. In the tutorial they are using "Google plugin for eclipse" to build and deploy the application on to the App Engine.
   I know I can deploy it on the local machine (for development purpose), but can I use Tomcat for deploying this.
2. When I use my local machine for development, how to configure OAuth2 redirect URL. The reason I am confused with this is because the application will deployed on the local machine. Will it mean I cannot use OAuth2 redirect URL will developing?

Your help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. If you want to use GAE, you need to deploy to GAE, not Tomcat. But there's no need to use GAE just to access Google contacts, if you're not using it already.

Comment: Daniel, I have a web application and I need to the user to import their contacts to the web application. So do I really need to use GAE, I reckon I am getting a little mixed up there...

Comment: No, as Zig says you are mixing up two unrelated tutorials. There are plenty of examples around on how to use the Contacts API from a normal web app - you probably want to start [with the actual docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up and reading unrelated tutorials. Gae tutorials are about gae not a random deployment to something else like tomcat.
Look at the contacts api directly. There are also many tutorials on how to do oauth for a client app.

Comment: Thanx Zig,  I have a web application and I need to the user to import their contacts to the web application. So do I really need to use GAE, I reckon I am getting a little mixed up there...

Comment: You dont need gae particularly since you already have a webapp. Look at the api examples that dont use gae. Some things are easier from gae but not that much harder on any other webapp.